# Autopurge of Elasticsearch index when exceed the hard disk size using bash script

Tags: json, linux, bash, curl, elasticsearch

I'm new to bash script, i want to make automation to delete the old saved record in elasticsearch. I can Perform this action by manually using curl command,

```
   " curl -XDELETE 'index name/_query' -d '
    {
      "query": 
      {
        "range": 
                    {
          "eventType_timestamp": 
                      { 
                      "gte": "2016-05-30T07:00:00.000Z",
                      "lte": "2016-06-15T06:59:59.999Z"
          }
        }
      }
    }'
```

Instead of passing the date manually, I want to parse the date automatically by shell script. I retrieved the date and stored in a fields when I pass those fields into script I am getting some error

```
   " curl -XDELETE 'index name/_query' -d '
    {
      "query": 
      {
        "range": 
                    {
          "eventType_timestamp": 
                      { 
                      "gte": $from_dataset_date,
                      "lte": $to_dataset_date
          }
        }
      }
    }'"
```

**Error**: This is error I am getting while run the above curl

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"jsonparse_exception","reason":"jsonparse_exception: Unrecognized token '$fromdatasetdate': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: [B@ba52ee7; line: 9, column: 33]"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"","node":"-oHm1uxQQ6e7RTnCaWtQEw","reason":{"type":"query_parsing_exception","reason":"Failed to parse","index":"-dd.","caused_by":{"type":"json_parse_exception","reason":"json_parse_exception: Unrecognized token '$from_dataset_date': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: [B@ba52ee7; line: 9, column: 33]"}}}]},"status":400}
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems it is a problem with quoting - combination with single quote, double quote and escaping . Curl send json data. Bash variable should be in double quotes but json data should start with single quote.

Example:

```
data="'"'{"json": "finish string after single quote ->", '"\"$BASH_VAR\""',"json1": "finish data"}'"'"
```

In above example I used concatenate strings in single quote and double quote (`"'"'{..'` for `'` add to `{..` ).

Try something like this in bash script

```
curl -XDELETE 'index name/_query' -d "'"'
    {
      "query": 
      {
        "range": 
                    {
          "eventType_timestamp": 
                      { 
                      "gte": '"\"$from_dataset_date\""',
                      "lte": $to_dataset_date
          }
        }
      }
    }'"'"
```